# Is there a php framework that makes working with jquery & ajax easier?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, frameworks

I've been using Codeigniter for the past two years and really have become a big fan, but over the past year I've found myself writing more and more javascript than PHP.

In the begining, I would write everything with PHP, but now I find myself using $.ajax all the time. And I sort of feel like Im repeating myself between javascript and php.

I know that CI does give you some good control over ajax, but Im still having two write a ton of javascript and I'd like to consolidate if at all possible.

I guess what I am looking for is a php framework that integrates tightly with jQuery's $.ajax.

Comment: I can't imagine how much easier can jQuery get, it already makes using JavaScript a child play.

Comment: You have a dull imagination my friend...

Comment: Is it something like this you're looking for? http://codeigniter.com/wiki/jQuery/
Otherwise I think you need to specify what you are expecting.

Comment: @Peter Perhaps I do, but `.ajax` method is simple as it gets, if you find your self writing .ajax over and over again you should probably think more about your JavaScript application architecture.

Comment: @Repox, thanks for the example... but that big red heading saying WARNING scares me... and, the link to the class is broken :(

Comment: @Rebus, can you point me in the right direction for making a smarter JS architecture while leveraging a PHP framework to make the process easier?

Comment: It all revolves around your use cases and you didn't mention any, if you want AJAX CRUD interface to your data, you certainly don't want to write a JavaScript function for each single peace of data on your site, you want to generalise as much as possible. [Arend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262961/is-there-a-php-framework-that-makes-working-with-jquery-ajax-easier/6263072#6263072) gave a more solid example. For example, when using forms you can use jquery.form plugin and you'll never have to see low level API such as .ajax ever and still be able to POST your form data.

Comment: Almost everything I deal with is AJAX CRUD. I guess I'll give a greator dig into jQuery's form plugin, but I still think there is a great need for a PHP framework that accommodates the need for AJAX CRUD operations.

Comment: @Peter I agree with that, it's just that you said you were writing a lot of JavaScript, but I really doubt that it is PHP frameworks fault. What you are really after, I think, is a single point in server side framework to which your can deliver your AJAX requests. Something like REST or SOAP services etc.

Comment: @Peter Also check out [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#), it helps a lot with handling data communication between server and the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this piece of code in Javascript. Backend wise things are organized in a MVC type of organisation, so things affecting one module are usually grouped together. In general I also create a sperate module for a seperate model, but in some cases you may deviate from this principle.

My setup is with symfony at the back and plain jquery at the front. There are some approaches that automatize this part, like http://javascriptmvc.com/, I find it too restricting in many parts. Here is my workflow for integrating php and jquery.

**PHP**

Execute a piece of code and wrap it inside a try/catch block. This way error messages may be propagated to the frontend. This method helps in that regard to convert exceptions to a readable error. (to debug from json).

```
try {
    //... execute code ..  go about your buisness..
    $this->result = "Moved  " . count($files) . " files ";
    // result can be anything that can be serialized by json_encode()
} catch (Exception $e) {
   $this->error = $e->getMessage() . ' l: '  . $e->getLine() . ' f:' . $e->getFile();
   // return an error message if there is an exception. Also throw exceptions yourself to make your life easier.
}
// json response basically does something like echo json_encode(array("error" => $this->error, "result" => $this->result))
return $this->jsonResponse();
```

For error handling I often use this to parse errors.

```
public function parseException($e) {
    $result = 'Exception: "';
    $result .= $e->getMessage();
    $trace = $e->getTrace();
    foreach (range(0, 10) as $i) {
        $result .= '" @ ';
        if (!isset($trace[$i])) {
            break;
        }
        if (isset($trace[$i]['class'])) {
            $result .= $trace[$i]['class'];
            $result .= '->';
        }
        $result .= $trace[$i]['function'];
        $result .= '(); ';
        $result .= $e->getFile() . ':' . $e->getLine() . "\n\n";
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**Javascript side**

```
/**
 * doRequest in an ajax development tool to quickly execute data posts.
 * @requires jQuery.log
 * @param action (string): url for the action to be called. in config.action the prefix for the url can be set
 * @param data (object): data to be send. eg. {'id':5, 'attr':'value'}
 * @param successCallback (function): callback function to be executed when response is success
 * @param errorCallback (function): callback function to be executed when response is success
 */
jQuery.doRequest = function (action, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    if (typeof(successCallback) == "undefined") {
        successCallback = function(){};
    } 
    if (typeof(errorCallback) == "undefined") {
        errorCallback = function(data ){
            alert(data.error);
        };
    }
    jQuery.log(action);

    jQuery.post(action, data, function (data, status)
    {

        jQuery.log(data);
        jQuery.log(status);
        if (data.error !== null || status != 'success') {
            // error handler
            errorCallback(data);
        } else {
            successCallback(data);
        }
    },'json');
};
```

Note: the error callbacks are very nice if you combine them with something like [pNotify](http://pines.sourceforge.net/pnotify/)

Comment: Awesome stuff! I might be adding that to my toolbox. Thanks Arend!

Comment: @Peter: You also need to accept his answer if you are going that way besides thanking him.

Comment: @Ozair, Im gonna wait this out to see if I can get more insight on my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Look into Agile Toolkit, which is a **PHP UI Framework**. UI means it takes care of HTML, JavaScript, CSS and AJAX while allowing you to develop in plain, object-oriented PHP language.

http://agiletoolkit.org/intro/javascript

There is also a blog post comparing it with CodeIgniter: http://agiletoolkit.org/blog/agile-toolkit-for-codeigniter-developer/

p.s. I'm co-author for Agile Toolkit.

Comment: That looks pretty nifty! Ill have to really digg into that.

Comment: very easy to use, so many features at so little overhead. suggested.